# Why is my for loop not pulling the correct data from my array of objects?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, click, toggle

I have successfully got my jQuery to load individual data from my array of objects but when I tried to add a jQuery click event to enable a toggle feature (that loads the image of the div into a bigger 'fullscreen' view) it only loads the very last array item's data.

Sample of my array of objects I'm calling allPictures:

```
var allPictures = [
    {
        name: "Elevated",
        number: 0,
        desc: "Hand Forged Steel Sculpture. Dimensions: 18\" diameter 16\” Height. Finish: Blue Opal, powdered pigment",
        tag: "Sculpt"
    },
    {
        name: "Paradise",
        number: 1,
        desc:"Hand Sculpted Auto Entry Gate. Material: Aluminum. Finish: Marine grade primer/Bronze Verde gre Faux/Hand Painted Bird of ParadiseFlowers",
        tag:"Metal"
    },
    {
        name: "Herculean Trellis",
        number: 2,
        desc:"Rose bush Trellis; Hand Forged. Material: Steel. Dimensions: 6’6”Hx3’9”W Weight: 340lbs. Finish: Bronze highlight rub/Bees wax",
        tag:"Metal"
    },
    {
        name: "Modern Cable Railing",
        number: 3,
        desc:"Exterior Stainless Steel Cable Railing. Material: 304 Stainless Steel structure/316 S.S. Cable hardware. Dimensions: 3’6”Hx3”Wx270 linear ft. Finish: Epoxy Primer/Polyurethane",
        tag:"Metal"
    }]
```

Relevant for loop from same JS file:

```
// on PORTFOLIO page, this code loops through ALL PICTURES WITHIN div's
for (i=0;i<allPictures.length;i++) {

    $imgNum = allPictures[i].number;
    $imgTitle = allPictures[i].name;
    $imgDesc = allPictures[i].desc;

    $newDIV = $('<div>');
    $newDIV.addClass("image-holder");
    $newDIV.attr("onclick","toggleView()");

    // create newPICTURE
    $newPICTURE = $('<img>');
    //Change the src using jQuery's attr method + the allPics number
    $newPICTURE.attr("src", `images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`);
    // append PIC to DIV
    $newDIV.append($newPICTURE);

    // creating infoOverlay
    $newOVERLAY = $('<div>');
    $newOVERLAY.addClass("info-overlay");
    $newOVERLAY.text(allPictures[i].name);
    $newDIV.append($newOVERLAY);

        // THIS is the function I'd like to change all the relevant info for the toggled fullscreen overlay
    $newDIV.click(function(){
            $('#centerpiece-img').attr('src',`images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`)
            $('#centerpiece-title').text($imgTitle);
            $('#centerpiece-desc').text($imgDesc);
        });

    // append DIV to container
    $('#art-display').append($newDIV);

}
```

I'm tired and this is my first post, so sorry If I haven't formatted this post perfectly.

toggleView method on different script/js file - toggle.js (this is EVERYTHING on toggle.js):

```
function toggleView() {
console.log('toggle.js connected')

// display OVERLAY
var viewerOverlay = document.getElementById('viewerOverlay');

if (viewerOverlay.style.display === 'none') {
    viewerOverlay.style.display = "block";
} else {
    viewerOverlay.style.display = "none";
}
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("viewerOverlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

[this is a pic of it CORRECTLY loading the right image in the thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5KOE.jpg)

[this is the image that loads when I click on "Elevate" (the 1st image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhFIt.jpg)

EDIT: Added photos and changed array to hopefully communicate my problem better.

EDIT2: Added the toggleView() method

Comment: means when you click on image. its open other/different image ??

Comment: Can you please add the toggleView method?

Comment: why do you have two functions on click of the div ??
$newDIV.attr("onclick","toggleView()");  and
 $newDIV.click(function(){
            $('#centerpiece-img').attr('src',`images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`)
            $('#centerpiece-title').text($imgTitle);
            $('#centerpiece-desc').text($imgDesc);
        });

Comment: @sabbir.alam - added the toggleView method in my Edit2

Comment: @rakshitjat - correct, it's loading the data from the last item in the array - doesn't matter if i click on the 1st 2nd 3rd of 4th/last, it will always load the 4th/last image

Comment: @sonali - well, i'm a junior level dev, so it may not be ideal, but i have one function (toggleView) to actually display and hide the #viewerOverlay ID -- and this is working as intended.

i built the other function into the same For loop that loads all the data for each div because i didn't know how to access the data object from a function in my toggle.js toggleView() function

Comment: How about 
$newDIV.click(function(){
            toggleViews();
            $('#centerpiece-img').attr('src',`images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`)
            $('#centerpiece-title').text($imgTitle);
            $('#centerpiece-desc').text($imgDesc);
        });

Comment: its always update/change src so when loop in last round then its change src so its always show last data/record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one...I just your code copy and modify code..

```
// on PORTFOLIO page, this code loops through ALL PICTURES WITHIN div's
    for (i=0;i<allPictures.length;i++) {

    $imgNum = allPictures[i].number;
    $imgTitle = allPictures[i].name;
    $imgDesc = allPictures[i].desc;

    $newDIV = $('<div>');
        $newDIV.addClass("image-holder");
        $newDIV.attr("onclick","toggleView()");      
        $newDIV.attr("data-imagePath",`images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`);
        $newDIV.attr("data-imageTitle",$imgTitle);

        $newDIV.attr("data-imgDesc",$imgDesc);


    // create newPICTURE
    $newPICTURE = $('<img>');
        //Change the src using jQuery's attr method + the allPics number
        $newPICTURE.attr("src", `images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`);

        // append PIC to DIV
        $newDIV.append($newPICTURE);

    // creating infoOverlay
    $newOVERLAY = $('<div>');
        $newOVERLAY.addClass("info-overlay");

        $newOVERLAY.text(allPictures[i].name);

        $newDIV.append($newOVERLAY);

        // THIS is the function I'd like to change all the relevant info for the toggled fullscreen overlay
}
```

just write in your function

```
    function toggleView() {
        console.log('toggle.js connected')
    
    // display OVERLAY
    var viewerOverlay = document.getElementById('viewerOverlay');
    
    if (viewerOverlay.style.display === 'none') {


   imageData=$(this).data('imagePath');
   imageTitleData=$(this).data('imageTitle');
   imageDescData=$(this).data('imgDesc');
   $('#centerpiece-img').attr('src',imageData)
   $('#centerpiece-title').text(imageTitleData);
    $('#centerpiece-desc').text(imageDescData);
        viewerOverlay.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        viewerOverlay.style.display = "none";
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for diving into this with me.. This seems very close to me, but no data is loading. I might be missing something on my end but I made my code look like yours, so I'm not sure what...I added     console.log(imageTitleData) right before the $('#centerpiece-title').text(imageTitleData); part and my Console is just saying "undefined". By the way, I have the allPictures array of objects in the same jQuery (document.ready / $) block of code.. is that okay?

Comment: I just solved it! Thanks for putting me on the right track - I think I was thinking of data attributes in my mind but couldn't remember the name for them or how to even use them.

Using your answer, and the one from @Sajjad Ali , I realized that my main problem was that I was mixing JavaScript and jQuery in my two different scripts. I then realized I could access the data attributes with event.currentTarget (event.target selected the wrong div) and JS commands and update them with the data attributes you created for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below, we have comment the second click function on 'newDIV'. We are utilizing only toggleView function for updating image description.

```
for (i=0;i<allPictures.length;i++) {

    $imgNum = allPictures[i].number;
    $imgTitle = allPictures[i].name;
    $imgDesc = allPictures[i].desc;
//adding image description as data-attr

    $newDIV = $(`<div data-imgnumber='${$imgNum}' data-desc='${$imgDesc}'  data-title='${$imgTitle}'>`); // Adding current iteration number
        $newDIV.addClass("image-holder");
        $newDIV.attr("onclick","toggleView()");

    // create newPICTURE
    $newPICTURE = $('<img>');
        //Change the src using jQuery's attr method + the allPics number
        $newPICTURE.attr("src", `images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`);

        // append PIC to DIV
        $newDIV.append($newPICTURE);

    // creating infoOverlay
    $newOVERLAY = $('<div>');
        $newOVERLAY.addClass("info-overlay");

        $newOVERLAY.text(allPictures[i].name);

        $newDIV.append($newOVERLAY);

        // THIS is the function I'd like to change all the relevant info for the toggled fullscreen overlay

/*
As are showing selected image data in toggleView function so, REMOVE THIS CODE
        $newDIV.click(function(){
            $('#centerpiece-img').attr('src',`images/portfolio/img\ (${$imgNum}).jpg`)
            $('#centerpiece-title').text($imgTitle);
            $('#centerpiece-desc').text($imgDesc);
        });
*/
    // append DIV to container
    $('#art-display').append($newDIV);

}
```

and here is your updated toggleView function

```
function toggleView() {
    console.log('toggle.js connected')

    // display OVERLAY
    var viewerOverlay = document.getElementById('viewerOverlay');

    if (viewerOverlay.style.display === 'none') {

    // Here we are updating selected image data in bigger div
        $('#centerpiece-img').attr('src',`images/portfolio/img\ (${this.getAttribute("data-imgnumber")}).jpg`)
        $('#centerpiece-title').text(this.getAttribute("data-title"));
        $('#centerpiece-desc').text(this.getAttribute("data-desc"));


        viewerOverlay.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        viewerOverlay.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the right answer.. I think I may be doing something else wrong.  When I put all of toggleView() in a jQuery document.ready section it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleView" is not defined  When I **don't** have toggleView() wrapped in jQuery, I get: "Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function"